# CoreImage CIKMeans CIFilter Exception

Tags: ios, uiimage, core-image, cifilter, ciimage

I've been trying to use the `CIKMeans` `CIFilter` introduced with iOS 13.0, but I always end with an exception.

```swift
guard let kMeansFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIKMeans") else {
   fatalError("Could not initialize `CIKMeans` filter.")
}

kMeansFilter.setValue(ciImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
kMeansFilter.setValue(CIVector(cgRect: ciImage.extent), forKey: "inputExtent")
kMeansFilter.setValue(2, forKey: "inputCount")
kMeansFilter.setValue(10, forKey: "inputPasses")
kMeansFilter.setValue(NSNumber(value: true), forKey: "inputPerceptual")
kMeansFilter.setValue([CIColor(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 1), CIColor(red: 0, green: 1, blue: 1)], forKey: "inputMeans")

let outputImage = kMeansFilter.outputImage
```

The crash happen when getting the `outputImage` from the filter (last line).
[image: CIFilter CIKmeans Crash]

The problem seems to come from the seed values I set via the `inputMeans` key. The [documentation](https://cifilter.io/CIKMeans/) indicates that it can be passed as an image or an array of colors. I've tried both, but always run into the same problem.

Has anyone had success with the `CIKMeans` filter?

Comment: Have you tried passing `CIVectors` representing the colors?

Comment: Good suggestion @FrankSchlegel, but unfortunately I run into the same problem with `CIVector` instances.

Comment: Have you tried only a single color (or vector)?

Comment: I have tried with only one color and vector, but no success either.
My understanding is that the value for `inputCount` should match the number of seeds (colors/vectors), so I also changed that value to 1, but that didn't help either.

Comment: And setting a 1x1 `CIImage` containing the color also doesn't work?

Comment: Unfortunately not.
This is what I've tried:
`CIImage(color: CIColor(red: 0.2, green: 0.2, blue: 0.2, alpha: 1.0))`

Comment: I've also changed the extent so that it's 1x1 and not infinity.

Comment: The error even occurs when just initializing the kernel and asking if for its `outputImage` – without any parameters. This is definitely a bug in Core Image. It would be great if you could file a radar for this.

Comment: For what it's worth, this doesn't seem to happen anymore as of iOS 14 beta 1. I haven't actually been able to get a "palettize" image to show up, though. See https://github.com/noahsark769/NGCIKMeansExample